# Error while making signed apk in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, signed-apk

I trying to generate signed apk but i am getting these error while making signed apk. So please help me to fix this

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/178391822186315777/877528165529051196/unknown.png

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/178391822186315777/877548401108066324/Screenshot_2021-08-18_191133.png

Comment: The first error is clear - you cannot use different password for keystore and the key itself. The second points that you might have broken keystore. How did you create this keystore?

Comment: @Jakoss Do password of Keystore and key must be same?

I am creating keystore using android studio

Generate signed APK> Create new path > Any ZYX Path

Comment: yes, the message there is very clear. This particular store have to have this passwords same